# ¿Podeis explicarme este codigo? Tags de Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

He estado intentando conseguir poner el texto en negrita en mi propio "bloc de notas" y me he encontrado con que tengo que utilizar los tags (de texto). He leído varias explicaciones sobre ellos y sin embargo no me queda muy claro como utilizarlos. El resultado de esto es que he emulado el codigo que he visto y funciona, pero no lo comprendo. Siento mucho pediros algo tan trabajoso pero os agradecería mucho que me lo explicaseis o me adjuntaseis un link que me pueda solucionar estas dudas.

El código concreto es el siguiente:

```
def negritaApp():
    boldFont=font.Font(txtbox,txtbox.cget("font"))
    boldFont.configure(weight="bold")
    #creamos tag
    txtbox.tag_configure("bold", font=boldFont)
    #current tags
    current_tags=txtbox.tag_names("sel.first")
    #negrita ya está activado?
    if "bold" in current_tags:
        txtbox.tag_remove("bold","sel.first","sel.last")
    else:
        txtbox.tag_add("bold","sel.first","sel.last")
```

Siendo txtbox el ScrolledText donde se escribe.

Mis preguntas son las siguientes:

¿Cómo funciona ese tag_configure? ¿"bold" es un nombre que le damos a un tag creado por nosotros o una de tkinter que sirve para poner en negrita el texto? Imagino que es lo primero y que luego "font=boldFont" hace que se repita ese proceso a todo aquello que tenga el tag "bold". Pero no estoy seguro.

¿Cómo funciona el "sel.first" y el "sel.last"? Porque las explicaciones que leo dicen que actúan sobre lo que viene antes y después de lo seleccionado. Sin embargo, yo veo esto y me da la sensación de que simplemente están actuando sobre el texto seleccionado. Sino, no entiendo su función aquí.

Os pido ayuda, por favor.

EDIT: El codigo completo ya que me lo piden:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import scrolledtext
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import font
from io import open


#RAIZ
root=Tk()
root.title("Bloc de notas")

#FUNCIONES ARCHIVO

def nuevoApp():
    txtbox.delete("1.0",END)
def abrirApp():
    file=filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Abrir",initialdir="C://", filetypes=[("Archivo de texto","*.txt"),("Todos los archivos","*.*")])
    if file!="":
        file1=open(file,"r")
        file2=file1.read()
        file1.close()
        txtbox.delete("1.0",END)
        txtbox.insert("1.0",file2)
def guardar2App():
    file=filedialog.asksaveasfilename(title="Guardar como...", initialdir="C://", defaultextension=".txt", filetypes=[("Archivo de texto","*.txt")])
    if file!="":
        file1=open(file,"w")
        file1.write(txtbox.get("1.0", END))
        file1.close()
def salirApp():
    answer=messagebox.askquestion("Salir","¿Desea salir de la aplicación?")
    if answer=="yes":
        root.destroy()

#FUNCIONES EDITAR

def deshacerApp():
    txtbox.edit_undo()
def rehacerApp():
    txtbox.edit_redo()
def borrarApp():
    txtbox.delete("sel.first","sel.last")
def cortarApp():
    global copy
    if txtbox.selection_get():
        copy=txtbox.selection_get()
        txtbox.delete("sel.first","sel.last")
        root.clipboard_clear()
        root.clipboard_append(copy)
def copiarApp():
    global copy
    if txtbox.selection_get():
        copy=txtbox.selection_get()
        root.clipboard_clear()
        root.clipboard_append(copy)
def pegarApp():
    global copy
    position=txtbox.index(INSERT)
    txtbox.insert(position,copy)

def negritaApp():
    boldFont=font.Font(txtbox,txtbox.cget("font"))
    boldFont.configure(weight="bold")
    #creamos tag
    txtbox.tag_configure("bold", font=boldFont)
    #current tags
    current_tags=txtbox.tag_names("sel.first")
    #negrita ya está activado?
    if "bold" in current_tags:
        txtbox.tag_remove("bold","sel.first","sel.last")
    else:
        txtbox.tag_add("bold","sel.first","sel.last")



#MENU
menu1=Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu1)

menuArchivo=Menu(menu1, tearoff=0, background="#E3A16B", activebackground="#785538")
menu1.add_cascade(label="Archivo",menu=menuArchivo)
menuArchivo.add_command(label="Nuevo", command=nuevoApp)
menuArchivo.add_command(label="Abrir", command=abrirApp)
menuArchivo.add_command(label="Guardar")
menuArchivo.add_command(label="Guardar como",command=guardar2App)
menuArchivo.add_separator()
menuArchivo.add_command(label="Cerrar")
menuArchivo.add_command(label="Salir", command=salirApp)

menuEditar=Menu(menu1,tearoff=0, background="#E3A16B", activebackground="#785538")
menu1.add_cascade(label="Editar",menu=menuEditar)
menuEditar.add_command(label="Deshacer", command=deshacerApp)
menuEditar.add_command(label="Rehacer", command=rehacerApp)
menuEditar.add_command(label="Borrar",command=borrarApp)
menuEditar.add_separator()
menuEditar.add_command(label="Cortar",command=cortarApp)
menuEditar.add_command(label="Copiar", command=copiarApp)
menuEditar.add_command(label="Pegar", command=pegarApp)
menuEditar.add_separator()
menuEditar.add_command(label="Buscar")
menuEditar.add_command(label="Seguir buscando")
menuEditar.add_command(label="Remplazar")
menuEditar.add_separator()
menuEditar.add_command(label="Seleccionar todo")

menuLetra=Menu(menu1,tearoff=0, background="#E3A16B", activebackground="#785538")
menu1.add_cascade(label="Letra",menu=menuLetra)
menuLetra.add_command(label="Negrita", command=negritaApp)
menuLetra.add_command(label="Fuente")

#VENTANA ADAPTABLE
myFrame=Frame(root)
myFrame.config()
myFrame.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky=E+W+N+S)

root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
myFrame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
myFrame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

#SCROLLED TEXT
txtbox = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(myFrame, width=50,height=20,bg="#FFDFC4", selectbackground="#694A31", undo=True)
txtbox.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=E+W+N+S)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: tag_configure hace exactamente eso, configura un tag. Necesita dos parámetros, el nombre que le quieres poner y lo que hace, en este caso le llamas "bold" y le dices que tiene que cambiar la fuente por la `boldFont`. El `sel.first` y `sel.last` hacen referencia al primer y último carácter de la actual selección, basicamente a `tag_add` le pasas 3 cosas, primero, el tag que aplicará, segundo *desde dónde* y tercero *hasta donde*, osea, pone "bold" desde el primer char seleccionado hasta el último.

Comment: Podrias poner el codigo completo por favor? A mi no me funciona, por eso te lo pido.

Comment: @Benito-B Muchísimas gracias. Mas o menos era lo que imaginaba; pero de alguna manera me acabé haciendo un lio en la cabeza y muy frustrado. Te lo agradezco mucho.

Comment: @DanteS. He editado con todo el código que llevo, por si te sirve. Pero ten en cuenta que yo soy novatisimo y seguro que hay mil maneras de hacerlo mejor. Funcionar, funciona.

Comment: Gracias por el código c: El comentario de Benito te sirvió o quieres que te de una respuesta explicando lo que hace la función línea por línea?

Comment: @DanteS. Hombre, ya que te ofreces jajaja cuanto mejor lo comprenda, mejor :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como dijo Jack el Destripador, vamos por partes.
En esta respuesta me voy a dedicar a explicar lo que hace cada linea del código.

## Linea 1

```
boldFont=font.Font(txtbox,txtbox.cget("font"))
```

En esta línea se crea una copia de la fuente original del ScrolledText y la guarda en la variable `boldFont`. Lo que hace `txtbox.cget("font")` es devolver la fuente actual de todo el ScrolledText.

## Linea 2

```
boldFont.configure(weight="bold")
```

En esta linea se hace que la fuente sea de formato negrita.

## Linea 3

```
txtbox.tag_configure("bold", font=boldFont)
```

Creamos/configuramos el tag "bold". Es dificil de explicar que es un tag, pero haré mi mejor esfuerzo. Un tag es una o más zonas del texto con características en común. Un ejemplo de un tag sería la zona seleccionada de un texto. El texto seleccionado tiene un color blanco con fondo azul.
Pero volviendo a lo que hace la linea, hace que todas las zonas del texto donde está el tag "bold", tengan la fuente que creamos en las dos lineas anteriores, es decir, las letras en negrita.

## Linea 4

```
current_tags=txtbox.tag_names("sel.first")
```

Obtiene dentro de que tags está la primer letra seleccionada y guarda esos tags dentro de la variable current_tags.
`sel.first` es la ubicación de la primera letra seleccionada.

## Linea 5

```
if "bold" in current_tags:
```

Revisa si el tag "bold" está en current_tags.
Si interpretamos la linea anterior y esta juntas, vemos que el objetivo es saber si la primera letra seleccionada está o no en negrita.

## Linea 6

```
txtbox.tag_remove("bold","sel.first","sel.last")
```

Esta linea remueve el tag "bold" de la zona seleccionada.
El objetivo de esta linea es que las letras seleccionadas que estén en negrita dejen de estarlo.

## Linea 7

```
else:
```

Lo que está debajo de esta linea es lo que sucederá si la condición de la linea 5 no se cumple. Es decir, la primera letra seleccionada NO está en negrita.

## Linea 8

```
txtbox.tag_add("bold","sel.first","sel.last")
```

Agrega el tag "bold" a todas las letras seleccionadas.
`sel.last` es la ubicación de la ultima letra seleccionada.
El objetivo de esta linea es poner en negrita cada letra seleccionada.

---

Y ualá! Me costó escribir esta respuesta, así que ojala te sirva c:

Comment: Si vas a votar negativo, no olvides explicar el por que aqui abajo o en el chat si vienes de allí.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias! Es tal y como me imaginaba, pero  varias cosas las intuía y no las sabia con seguridad. Ahora que me lo has confirmado, podré aprender esto y utilizarlo con mucha más seguridad y fluidez. Lo considero muy importante.

Por cierto, yo no he votado negativo en ninguna parte =/

Comment: De nada! me alegro de que sirva! Es que ese comentario lo hice para todo aquel que votase negativo. No a vos en particular.